# Error: Visual Studio Cordova Command failed with exit code 69

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I'm working on Hybrid mobile application using cordova. When I tried to deploy it to Mac using visual studio it gives following error message.

```
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0A5IORSI.S5U\packages\vs-mda
1>MDAVSCLI : error - Build failed with error /Users/admin/remote-builds/builds/888/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 69
1>Error : Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error /Users/admin/remote-builds/builds/888/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 69:
```

Any help or suggestion to fix this?

More info: I'm getting following error message in Remote Server (mac)

```
error BuildFailedWithError [ '/Users/admin/remote-builds/builds/888/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 69' ]
```

Comment: For the remote build on your Mac, are you using the vs-mda-remote server?

Comment: @JordanMatthiesen Yes...

Answer (score 0):

We recommend to use VS 2015 and not VS2013 since Microsoft has recently changed the Cordova App structure to comply with recent CLI changes. Please open up your project using VS2015 which will upgrade and slight change the current structure of your project.

Let me know if you have any other issues.